# stopping the css animation process

Tags: html, css

first of all sorry for my English. I am new in css. i have given this effect to text.
    i just want to stop this animation once its done for all the sentences,
    there are 6 sentences with 3sec delay between each two,after last sentence completion 
    i want to display all sentences together and wants to keep as it is,but it   will again 
     start animation from first sentence.how can i stop this?
     please help me if anyone knows.thanks in advance.this is my css code

```css
.rw-words-1 span{
  font-size: 150%;
  line-height: 120%;
  -webkit-animation: rotateWordsFirst 18s linear infinite 0s;
  -ms-animation: rotateWordsFirst 18s linear infinite 0s;
  animation: rotateWordsFirst 18s linear infinite 0s;
}
.rw-words span:nth-child(2) { 
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s; 
  -ms-animation-delay: 3s; 
  animation-delay: 3s; 
}
.rw-words span:nth-child(3) { 
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s; 
  -ms-animation-delay: 6s; 
  animation-delay: 6s; 
}
.rw-words span:nth-child(4) { 
  -webkit-animation-delay: 9s; 
  -ms-animation-delay: 9s; 
  animation-delay: 9s; 
}
.rw-words span:nth-child(5) { 
  -webkit-animation-delay: 12s; 
  -ms-animation-delay: 12s; 
  animation-delay: 12s; 
}
.rw-words span:nth-child(6) { 
  -webkit-animation-delay: 15s; 
  -ms-animation-delay: 15s; 
  animation-delay: 15s; 
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateWordsFirst {
  0% { opacity: 0; -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; width: 0px;}
  5% { opacity: 1; -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; width: 100%;}
  17% { opacity: 1; }
  20% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes rotateWordsFirst {
  0% { opacity: 0; -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in; width: 0px;}
  5% { opacity: 1; -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out; width: 100%;}
  17% { opacity: 1; }
  20% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes rotateWordsFirst {
  0% { opacity: 0;   animation-timing-function: ease-in; width: 0px;}
  5% { opacity: 1;   animation-timing-function: ease-out; width: 100%;}
  17% { opacity: 1; }
  20% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<section class="rw-wrapper">
  <h2 class="rw-sentence">
    <div class="rw-words rw-words-1">
        <span>beautiful websites</span>
        <span>interesting apps</span>
        <span>impactful identities</span>
        <span>working strategies</span>
        <span>incredible gadgets</span>
        <span>intelligent systems</span>
    </div>
  </h2>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is due to `infinite` in `animation` inside `.rw-words-1 span`.Just remove that and it works fine.

```css
.rw-words-1 span{
  font-size: 150%;
  line-height: 120%;
  -webkit-animation: rotateWordsFirst 18s linear;
  -ms-animation: rotateWordsFirst 18s linear;
  animation: rotateWordsFirst 18s linear;
}
.rw-words span:nth-child(2) { 
  -webkit-animation-delay: 3s; 
  -ms-animation-delay: 3s; 
  animation-delay: 3s; 
}
.rw-words span:nth-child(3) { 
  -webkit-animation-delay: 6s; 
  -ms-animation-delay: 6s; 
  animation-delay: 6s; 
}
.rw-words span:nth-child(4) { 
  -webkit-animation-delay: 9s; 
  -ms-animation-delay: 9s; 
  animation-delay: 9s; 
}
.rw-words span:nth-child(5) { 
  -webkit-animation-delay: 12s; 
  -ms-animation-delay: 12s; 
  animation-delay: 12s; 
}
.rw-words span:nth-child(6) { 
  -webkit-animation-delay: 15s; 
  -ms-animation-delay: 15s; 
  animation-delay: 15s; 
}
@-webkit-keyframes rotateWordsFirst {
  0% { opacity: 0; -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; width: 0px;}
  5% { opacity: 1; -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; width: 100%;}
  17% { opacity: 1; }
  20% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@-ms-keyframes rotateWordsFirst {
  0% { opacity: 0; -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in; width: 0px;}
  5% { opacity: 1; -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out; width: 100%;}
  17% { opacity: 1; }
  20% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
@keyframes rotateWordsFirst {
  0% { opacity: 0;   animation-timing-function: ease-in; width: 0px;}
  5% { opacity: 1;   animation-timing-function: ease-out; width: 100%;}
  17% { opacity: 1; }
  20% { opacity: 0; }
  100% { opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<section class="rw-wrapper">
  <h2 class="rw-sentence">
    <div class="rw-words rw-words-1">
        <span>beautiful websites</span>
        <span>interesting apps</span>
        <span>impactful identities</span>
        <span>working strategies</span>
        <span>incredible gadgets</span>
        <span>intelligent systems</span>
    </div>
  </h2>
</section>
```

Comment: hey thanks its working.but i want to play it only once.wanna give that effect only once in all.and print it all together.that is not working.please tell me the solution.

Comment: @ValarDohaeris I am not sure whether it can be achieved by the way the code is written for that to achieve you have to completely change the CSS